# How to maximize Safari window with JavaScript for Automation (JXA)?

Tags: safari, automation, applescript, javascript-automation

I'm looking for a way to maximize the Safari window using [JavaScript for Automation (JXA)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/Introduction.html).

I'm able to open Safari and to bring the window to front, but I can't find a way to open it in fullscreen.

```
var safari = Application('Safari');
safari.includeStandardAdditions = true; 
safari.quit(); // Avoid having multiple Safari windows open
safari.activate(); // Start Safari and bring to front  
var document = safari.documents[0];
document.url = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
```

Answer (score 2):

To go full screen in Safari, you could code…

```
var se = Application('System Events');
delay(1);
se.keystroke('f', { using: ['control down','command down'] });
```

Put it after your code.